# python bokeh vbar_stack streaming glyph doesn't update

Tags: python, streaming, bokeh

I want to create a real time updating plot with stacked bars. During the session there has to be adding new bars. But the updating function only works if I refresh the browser. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, curdoc
import random

x = 0
def get_data():
    global x
    x = x + random.random()
    new = {
        'x':[x],
        'y1':[random.random()],
        'y2':[random.random()]
    }
    return new

type = ["y1", "y2"]
colors = ["blue", "yellow"]
source = ColumnDataSource({'x':[], 'y1':[], 'y2':[]})

def update():
    new=get_data()
    source.stream(new)

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400)
p.vbar_stack(type, x='x', width=0.5, color=colors, source=source)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 60)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Bokeh: issue [`#7823`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7823) resolved in PR [`#7833`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/7833). You will need to update to version `0.12.16` or newer.